# Microsoft VC++ 2005 SP1 and 2008 SP1 Redistributable Package

Tags: visual-c++, package, redistributable

I have an application that requires Microsoft VC++ 2005 (SP1) Redistributable Package.

I know that I can just download it and install it.

The problem is, in our server, there is Microsoft VC++ 2008 (SP1) Redistributable Package already installed.

Now, do I still need to install the 2005 (SP1) version?

Or the 2008 (SP1) is "backward compatible" with 2005 (SP1)?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install the 2005 redist :- the package it installs consists of dlls called MSVCR80.dll, whereas the 2008 redist has the MSVCR90.dll files.
They are not compatible.

Comment: Oh ok, and they both can co-exist without breaking each other applications?

Comment: They have different names for the dlls, so yes. Actually they are installed into the WinSxS store, that seperates dlls by name and hash-of-public-key, so even if the dll names were the same they could co-exist peacefully.